# Why is my glm rotate function not properly rotating my camera?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

I have been trying to get a camera in my world that can rotate and look around a 3D scene actually working for a very long time now. I don't understand why my camera is behaving so strangely when I rotate it moving back and forth not rotating how it should. I have been stuck on this and would really appreciate it if anyone could let me know what I could correct. Thanks.

::MAIN MATH

```
glm::mat4 look(1.0f);
glm::mat4 model_view(1.0f);
glm::mat4 look_around(1.0f);
glm::mat4 the_perspective(1.0f);
float leftrightlook;

the_perspective = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), static_cast<float>(width)/height , -7.1f, 
150.0f);

look_around = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), (leftrightlook), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));


glm::vec3 UP(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glm::vec3 position(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glm::vec3 viewdirection(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

look = glm::lookAt(position, position + viewdirection, UP);

model_view = look_around * look;
```

::SHADER MATRIX MULTIPLICATION

```
gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0) * the_perspective * model_view;
```

Comment: your matrix multiplication orders are totally screwed up.

Comment: @derhass How can I fix them?

Comment: The standard way in OpenGL is `world_to_camera*model_to_world*model*data`. So, in your case `perspective*model_view*position`.

Comment: @Quimby I tried this and got a blank screen. could this have to do with anything?

Comment: @chiefus blank screen means your camera is facing wrongly or its too close/far (you know in GL perspective camera is usually viewing in `-Z` direction and znear,zfar are also an issue as matrix origin is the focal point not the viewing plane so its usual to step back by znear or more ...). Also it might be wrong front face setting if CULL_FACE is enabled

Comment: @Spektre ill check for this stuff thanks.